# Steps to create workflow using Mule ESB?

Tags: documentation, workflow

If you had to create a list of steps that a non-technical business layperson would understand for implementing workflows in something like Mule ESB -- what would it look like?  The scenario would be to describe how the ESB is used to perform integration between two disparate systems and the steps you would need to perform to get the job done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An Enterprise Service Bus is a technical middleware for system integration. It is doubtful whether mixing the business aspects into the picture makes sense. For business people to look at a picture and 'get it', the technical aspects would either be abstracted away and or require a tacit understanding of the technology. Better to keep them separate.

On the business logic level you should use BPML for workflow modelling: 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_Process_Modeling_Notation

The technical aspects of a service bus are captured through Enterprise Architecture Integration patterns: 
http://www.eaipatterns.com/toc.html

The EAI view is already abstract, but expecting business people to understand this is like handing them UML diagrams and assuming they're literate by nature (alas, they are not).